# LINQ - ConflictChangeException

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

I'm currently facing an issue that I currently seem to get around.

We have a table in a database for articles. Upon saving - an API call is made to a different vendor which will after some time update the column of the row with their order number.

However if the call is delayed and a user is editing the article they will receive a `ConflictChangeException` that simply says that the article was altered and that they have to close and reopen it.

Now I'd like to catch the exception and IF the reason for the conflict would be that this vendor has altered the column to do some magic with `RefreshMode` but IF NOT then still throw the exception as another user has altered the article.

The big issue is the SQL-server `timestamp` or `row-version` (what have you) that puts the proverbial stick in the wheel. I can't reload the values before an update with new order number from the vendor because there's still a conflict in that `timestamp` column.

In the LINQ to SQL model the `timestamp` property is set to

```
 <Column(Storage:="_Timestamp", AutoSync:=AutoSync.Always, DbType:="rowversion NOT NULL", CanBeNull:=false, IsDbGenerated:=true, IsVersion:=true, UpdateCheck:=UpdateCheck.Never)>  _
```

Since the `UpdateCheck` is set to never and `IsDbGenerated` is set to `true` I thought that LINQ would ignore it upon a conflict but no.

Is this a lost cause? Will I just have to keep telling the user that a change was made and that they have to reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by catching the `ChangeConflictException` and then looping through the `MemberChangeConflict` and doing some corrections and throwing the exception if they were unhandled.

```
Catch ex As System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException
    For Each ooc As System.Data.Linq.ObjectChangeConflict In data.ChangeConflicts
        Dim conflict As System.Data.Linq.MemberChangeConflict = ooc.MemberConflicts.ToList().Find(Function(p) p.Member.Name = "VendorUpdatedTable")
        If Not IsNothing(Conflict) Then
            For Each mcc As System.Data.Linq.MemberChangeConflict In ooc.MemberConflicts
                If mcc.Member.Name = "UserId" Then
                    If (CInt(mcc.OriginalValue) <> CInt(mcc.DatabaseValue)) Then
                        Throw ex
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
                If mcc.Member.Name = "VendorTableName" Then
                    mcc.Resolve(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues)
                Else 
                    mcc.Resolve(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues)
                End If
             Next
         Else : Throw ex
         End If
```